# Linking fails with filenames using Unicode characters

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm going to create an .exe file from the (existing) file `MonodyFrèreJacques.hs`. However, when i give the command:

```
ghc --make MonodyFrèreJacques.hs
```

I get this error message:

```
Linking MonodyFrèreJacques.exe ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib/../mingw/bin/windres.exe
 can't open file `**MonodyFrÜreJacques**.exe.manifest': No such file or directory
```

Using WinGHCi the result is similar: the file not found is `**MonodyFršreJacques**.exe.manifest`

Given that `è` is `U+00E8`, is my mistake or is a compiler error?